# I downloaded aws.phar, but can't require it

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, phar

I downloaded aws.phar from [Official repository of the AWS SDK for PHP](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php)

I put the downloaded file named aws.phar in my my project.

```
require 'aws.phar';
```

It's under the same directory with my php file.

Anyone knows how to deal with it?
quite the same like : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=399182&#399182

Answer (score 2):

If your installed version of PHP includes [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) (a patch for the default installation of PHP to improve security), then it disallows phars by default.

Both Ubuntu and Debian distributions come with Suhosin enabled by default.

To allow it to work, you need to add an exception for phar.

Edit the file located at '/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/suhosin.ini':

```
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think it maybe helpful for others.

Answer (score 2):

I have soloved my problem with Composer.
At first, I thought Composer is for php default settings, but it is for the project that you created. You just need to create a file named "composer.json" in your project's directory. First navigate to the directory in the terminal, the rest steps are the same as show in [aws/aws-sdk-php](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php#installing-via-composer)